# How can I run the Uniswap Dapp locally for sepolia testnet

Tags: uniswap, frontend, uniswapv2

I am trying to play around with the Uniswap contracts, by creating pools then swapping etc. The problem I'm facing is that Uniswap V2 doesn't support the sepolia network, V3 does.

So when I interact with the V2 contracts on sepolia(The ones deployed by the community), I can't actually interact with them through any frontend.And it's quite inconvenient to constantly interact with etherscan and CLI.

I was wondering if I could run the uniswap dapp locally by adding the sepolia network support for V2?
I am not very good with frontends, if anyone can help me the navigate through the steps for the above goal, that will help me a lot